# Run sails.js with least privileges in Production

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js 0.10.5 on Node 0.10.33 on Ubuntu Trusty. I'd like to execute the node process as a non-root user with the least possible privileges in the production environment. I'm comfortable with the various options for binding to ports below 1024 but I'm more concerned with directory permissions.

Ideally, I'd prefer the node process only have write access to its log files and nothing else. It should only have read access to the directory containing app.js and below.

At the moment I have needed to grant write access to the ./.tmp directory and also to the ./views directory due to the grunt tasks that run at startup. I'd rather perform the grunt tasks at deploy time as a different user instead of at run-time. The `sails www` command appeared promising but I couldn't get the desired outcome.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for running Sails.js with zero write access to its assets, views, etc?

Comment: This sounds like simply creating a user (with particular permissions to particular directories) and running `node` (or starting your app) as that user should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: `sudo -u foo grunt something` and `sudo -u bar node app.js` (or similar)?

Comment: @Whymarrh As far as I understand, running `node app.js` for the Sails-based application then launches `grunt` as a child process as the same user account. If someone knows how to separate the auto-execution of grunt from Sails, this would help answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to me seems to be to separate the grunt tasks that need the elevated privileges out into a separate file that you can call with a different user on deploy.  Then sails won't need to run anything and can be read only.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sails www` to build static assets

chmod -R 440 all files and directories, so that your user and the webserver (group) can access the files.

Use nginx/apache to host a webserver on port 80/443 and proxy requests to sails (running on its own port or over a unix socket).

Run sails using PM2 to keep it running and have it manage/collect logs.

Sails will lift, but will be unable to write its .tmp directory, which shouldn't even be necessary since all your static files will be routed to the www directory through nginx/apache.

Comment: Also, you could move the www directory outside of sails, and have it owned by the webserver.

Comment: This seems workable. Are you suggesting that sails.js will lift and continue running even if it fails to write to its .tmp directory? I also found that sails/grunt was trying to write to the ./views/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: I use PM2 with apache as proxy ( with mod WS ).

You can use one proxy like apache to route from port 80 to others internal server ports based on host.

With this way you can run multiple apps in same server.

It has a lot of usefull functions like see the logs how varius apps in terminal, restart and log crashed apps, run app as user, app status ... etc .

Pm2 link: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

PM2 configs: https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/development/ADVANCED_README.md#options

Comment: I am using PM2 in some places and Forever in others. In either case it is just ensuring that the node application continues running in the event of a failure. These tools have no impact on the permissions required by the node application.

Comment: yes, but you can use it with one proxy like apache or nginx

Comment: As per the first paragraph of my question, supporting port 80 with limited permissions is a solved problem via a proxy like Apache or Nginx, or via iptables port mapping, or via cap_net_bind_service.

I'm aiming to run the node application with zero write-access to its source files.